# Holding control, shift and v, using only one key

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I am using lightroom for this hotkey. I dont know why is this doesn't work for me.

```
::{control}{sleep 5}{shift}{sleep 5}v
```

And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>(5x) then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Take a look at the SendInput command in the documentation. Also the `Sleep` commands must be on their own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>(5x) then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I don't know what you mean by that, because I can't see anything like that in your script. So I will just ignore it and do what the thread title and your script says/implies.

The following script will simulate pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> when you press the <kbd>A</kbd> key

```
SetKeyDelay, 5 ;wait 5 milliseconds between every keystroke
a::^+v
```

About your comment, I guess I know what you are on to, try this:

```
SetKeyDelay, 5 ;wait 5 milliseconds between every keystroke
2::
  SendInput, !f
  Sleep, 50
  SendInput, {Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Enter}
Return
```

Comment: 2::!+f+{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Enter}

Comment: It would be pretty usefull if you'd comment in full sentences.